# What's the difference between logical modality and epistemic modality?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics, modality

Logical modality includes logical necessity and logical possibility, while epistemic modality includes epistemic necessity and epistemic possibility. But when I read the explanation of these concepts in the book of Kearn (2011), I feel really confused. Can you explain them with 1~2 simple sentences or examples to distinguish them? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The phrase "logical modality" does not contrast with "epistemic modality" (except possibly in Kearn's book, which I have not read). Normally [the distinction in logic about types of modality](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/411621/15299) is between Epistemic modality, which is about logic and probability (_This may not be the place; She must be home by now_), as opposed to Deontic modality, which is about social permission and obligation (_He may not enter if he's armed; She must be home by midnight_).

Comment: @jlawler Yes, in the book, it said "Epistemic possibility includes logical possibility", but there is no explicit illustration about the relationship of epistemic necessity and logical necessity, which baffled me a lot till now. But anyway, thank you for your explanation!